# Query returning incorrect count

Tags: count

I have the following query.

```
SELECT a.link_field1 AS journo, count(a.link_id) as articles, AVG( b.vote_value ) AS score FROM dan_links a LEFT JOIN dan_votes b ON link_id = vote_link_id WHERE link_field1 <> '' and link_status NOT IN ('discard', 'spam', 'page') GROUP BY link_field1 ORDER BY link_field1, link_id
```

This query is returning a count of 3 for the first item in the list. What should be returned is

```
Journo | count | score
John S | 2 | 6.00
Joe B | 1 | 4
```

However for the first one John S, it returns a count of 3.

If I directly query

```
select * from dan_links where link_field1 = 'John S'
```

I get 2 records return as I would expect. I can't for the life of me figure out why the count is wrong, unless for some reason it is counting the records from the dan_vote table

How can I get the correct count, or is my query completely wrong?

EDIT: Contents of the tables

dan_links

```
link_id | link_field1 | link | source | link_status
1 | John S | http://test.com | test.com | approved
2 | John S | http://google.com | google | approved
3 | Joe B | http://facebook.com | facebook | approved
```

dan_votes

```
vote_id | link_id | vote_value
1 | 1 | 5
2 | 1 | 8
3 | 2 | 4
4 | 3 | 1
```

EDIT: it looks like it is counting the rows in the votes table for some reason

Comment: Posting the records (from the 2 tables) you were working with would be helpful.

Comment: So I deleted one of the records for link_id 1 in the votes table and the count comes in at 2 which is correct, but I can't see why it would be doing that because my count is on a.link_id

Comment: if you look at the second table, the link_id "1" appeared twice and "2" appear once making 3. The results is affected by JOIN not COUNT

Comment: Ok so is there a way to get a count within the same query for only the records that match the first half of the query i.e.

select count(*) from dan_links where link_field1='John S'

Without me individually querying for that count?

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing a left outer join with the condition link_id = vote_link_id for every matching record one row is created, some thing like

```
link_id | link_field1 | link | source | link_status|vote_id|vote_value
1 | John S | http://test.com | test.com | approved|1|5
1 | John S | http://test.com | test.com | approved|2|8
2 | John S | http://google.com | google | approved|3|4
3 | Joe B | http://facebook.com | facebook | approved|4|1
```

Now when you do group by on link_field1, you get count as 3 for John S

Nested query might work

```
SELECT journo,count(linkid) as articles,AVG(score) FROM
(SELECT a.link_field1 AS journo, AVG( b.vote_value ) AS score, a.link_id as linkid 
FROM dan_links a 
LEFT JOIN dan_votes b 
ON link_id = vote_link_id 
WHERE link_field1 <> '' 
and link_status NOT IN ('discard', 'spam', 'page') 
GROUP BY link_id 
ORDER BY link_field1, link_id) GROUP BY journo
```

The above query will give incorrect average as **((n1+n2)/2+n3)/2 != (n1+n2+n3)/3**, so use the below query

```
SELECT journo,count(linkid) as articles, SUM(vote_sum)/SUM(count(linkid)) 
FROM
    (SELECT a.link_field1 AS journo, SUM( b.vote_value ) AS vote_sum, a.link_id as linkid, count(a.link_id) as count_on_id
    FROM dan_links a 
    LEFT JOIN dan_votes b 
    ON link_id = vote_link_id 
    WHERE link_field1 <> '' 
    and link_status NOT IN ('discard', 'spam', 'page') 
    GROUP BY link_id 
ORDER BY link_field1, link_id) GROUP BY journo
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok so is there a way to get a count within the same query for only the records that match the first half of the query i.e.

select count(*) from dan_links where link_field1='John S'

Without me individually querying for that count?

Comment: One way is to first group by on the basis of link_id so that duplicate records can be taken care off, then group by on the resultant on the basis of link_field1 to get the count. Updated the answer with sample query